# ReadTheDocs trouble with sklearn/umap

Tags: python, read-the-docs

I've got a package which I've previously successfully built on ReadTheDocs, but this is no longer the case. My imports are as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy
import sys
from annoy import AnnoyIndex
from packaging import version
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
from umap.umap_ import fuzzy_simplicial_set
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
```

I cover these packages via mock importing in Sphinx.

```
autodoc_mock_imports = ['pandas','numpy','scipy','annoy','packaging','scipy.spatial','scipy.sparse','sklearn','sklearn.neighbors','sklearn.linear_model','umap','umap.umap_']
```

However, in spite of that, I appear to encounter issues when building ReadTheDocs side. It seems that despite being asked to mock `sklearn` up, the thing's trying to install it and failing.

```
Installed /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/bbknn/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bbknn-1.4.0-py3.7.egg
Processing dependencies for bbknn==1.4.0
Searching for scikit-learn
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/db/e2/9c0bde5f81394b627f623557690536b12017b84988a4a1f98ec826edab9e/scikit-learn-0.24.0.tar.gz#sha256=076369634ee72b5a5941440661e2f306ff4ac30903802dc52031c7e9199ac640
Best match: scikit-learn 0.24.0
Processing scikit-learn-0.24.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-1f85jnk0/scikit-learn-0.24.0/setup.cfg
Running scikit-learn-0.24.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-1f85jnk0/scikit-learn-0.24.0/egg-dist-tmp-mfl2n2vi
Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/easy_install-1f85jnk0/scikit-learn-0.24.0/setup.py", line 201, in check_package_status
    module = importlib.import_module(package)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/bbknn/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/bbknn/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/bbknn/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/bbknn/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/bbknn/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-1f85jnk0/scikit-learn-0.24.0/setup.py", line 306, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-1f85jnk0/scikit-learn-0.24.0/setup.py", line 292, in setup_package
  File "/tmp/easy_install-1f85jnk0/scikit-learn-0.24.0/setup.py", line 227, in check_package_status
ImportError: numpy is not installed.
scikit-learn requires numpy >= 1.13.3.
Installation instructions are available on the scikit-learn website: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html
```

Why is this happening? Could this be related to the way I require dependencies in `setup.py`, which somehow circumvents the mocks?

```
install_requires=['Cython','numpy','scipy','annoy','umap-learn','scikit-learn','packaging'],
```

I have hotfix-generated a docstring by removing `umap-learn` and `scikit-learn` from `install_requires`, but that's not an ideal solution. Anybody got anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on feedback from a helpful user, I eventually arrived at a less hack'y solution. Unfortunately, the discussion went AWOL because of an unhelpful user, who responded with `pip install -U numpy`, waited for me to figure it out, edited their answer and requested I accept it. Upon being denied, the answer and comment thread vanished. I don't even remember your name, helpful user, so I can't credit you for the tip.

Apparently ReadTheDocs uses an old pip, and requiring `pip>=19.0` makes scikit-learn not install from source. As such, I added that line to `docs/requirements.txt`, which I had previously set up to be a ReadTheDocs requirement file. This resulted in some progress - now rather than scikit-learn complaining about numpy, it was numba. Still, some synapses connected, and I just handled any dependency problems that arose via `docs/requirements.txt`, the final contents of which are:

```
pip>=19.0
numpy
llvmlite==0.35.0
```

This got the setup to clear. However, just because setup cleared, does not mean that `autodoc_mock_imports` can be stripped away for whatever reason. Not sure why this is.

As such, the quick and dirty solution from the OP wherein you just strip stuff out of `setup.py`'s `install_requires` is likely the easiest way around this. However, if you feel like faffing around to get it to be cleaner, and not requiring a dedicated non-functional commit to have documentation build, having a ReadTheDocs requirement file and installing numpy through it is likely to solve a lot of woes. No idea why llvmlite was also this fussy, and somehow worked when in the requirements file but not otherwise, but got there in the end.